# Design principles to consider when wrapping a 3rd party logger like log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, design-patterns, logging

I'm creating a logger for a company that has several types of .NET projects (Windows Services, ASP.NET, etc), and I was considering using log4net as my logger, but I don't want to be married to log4net, so I was thinking of wrapping it in my own assembly. I realize some developers don't recommend wrapping log4net because that would be an anti-pattern, but assuming I was going that route anyway, I had some questions:

I am planning to use the design principles mentioned in this article to design my wrapper (using factory method, interfaces, and reflection, I can simply decide which logger I want to use (whether log4net, elmah or something else) by specifying in the config file:
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/designing-c-software-with-interfaces/

Question is:

- Should I create this logger project in a separate Visual Studio solution and just use the dll in my client applications? If so, where would the configuration details for log4net go? Would that be supplied by the client application's config file? If so, is that good design?  For instance, if I decided to switch away from log4net to a different logging framework, I would not only have to change the config setting to specify the new concrete logger's assembly/class name, but would also have to remove the log4net config entries (and perhaps add the new logger's config entries). Is this considered as an acceptable design approach?

Comment: I recommend you study the architecture of the Common.Logging wrapper. It shows how the api should look like and how you configure it and how you use it across the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Oh my goodness your timing is awesome.  And that article is very relevant to me so thanks!  I am doing this very same thing right now.  I realized that log4net is a decent logger, but a terrible library for making a logger.

I agree with the article, in that you should not directly expose to log4net. Unless this is a small app it would be too difficult to switch later.  And log4net is showing age so that may happen.  I like the interface approach overall.

But, wrapping log4net it is a pain in the butt.  So in doing my prototype wrapper I feel like I rewrote 50% of log4net, and discarded 25%.  Some issues I found:

1. log4net will grab the "caller information" for you.  Normally that is great.  But if you wrap log4net, the caller information will point to your logger.  So you will have to explicitly grab it yourself.  But log4net doesn't provide a way for you to override the caller information.  So now you will have to create your own fields for the caller's file, line number, class, and package.  Thus, not only do you not gain the benefit here, but it is actually more work than just doing it yourself.
2. Log4net uses the old pre C#-4.0 method of grabbing the caller information which is slow.
3. Your will be unable to completely wrap log4net without wrapping the configuration.  The caller has to configure the loggers either in code or in their app.config.  If they do it in their app.config then they are putting log4net specific stuff in their app, so you failed to hide it with your wrapper.  But if you have your wrapper code automatically perform the configuration, you just lost the flexibility of log4net.  The third option is to make your own configuration, but then what good did log4net do for you?  You just rewrote another piece of it.
4. You are stuck with the log levels that come with log4net.  In our app, we want "categories" instead of "levels" which I then have to map to the log4net "levels" under the hood.  Now, all the predefined log4net filters are of no use to me.
5. Anyone using your wrapper still has to reference log4net in their project anyway.
6. If your wrapper needs a way to handle errors, or pass them back to the caller, you will have trouble.  log4net has its own internal error handling and you will need to hook into that and provide your own.  Otherwise, errors (like a misconfigured appender) will just go out to the console.  If it was designed as a library for making loggers, it would just throw the exception back up or provide a simple event.

One thing we wanted to get out of log4net is the ability to write to different outputs without us us having to write that code ourselves.  Ex: I've never written to the event log, and I think log4net can do that.  But it might be easier for me to rip out the Event logging code, rather than to try and wrap that.  Same thing with filters.

There are some other problems I had with log4net that aren't directly related to trying to wrap it necessarily.

1. The code is old.  The interfaces don't use generics where they should.  Lots of object.
2. They use the old System.Collections collections.  Similar to #1.
3. It has ifdefs for .NET 1 versus 2, and ifdefs for the obsolete compact framework.  ugh.
4. It is designed to log strings, not structured objects.  I made my own code to do so, and so did these people: http://stephenjamescode.blogspot.com/2014/01/logging-custom-objects-and-fields-with.html and http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/05/mapping-message-object-properties-to.html but this feels like basic functionality.
5. It doesn't support CSV and it is cumbersome to add. http://element533.blogspot.com/2010/05/writing-to-csv-using-log4net.html
6. It doesn't have any kind of logging "service"
7. It doesn't provide a way to read or parse the log.
8. I found it was more effort to configure the appenders than to write your own.  Ex: I mapped a bunch of fields to the AdoNetAppender, but it would have taken me *less* time to just rewrite AdoNetAppender.  Debugging a database field mapping in XML is harder than trying to debug the equivalent C# + ADO.NET code.  The XML is more verbose and less type safe.  This might be specific to me because I had a very structured set of data and a lot of fields.

Sorry for the really long post, I have lots and lots of thoughts on this topic.  I don't really dislike log4net, I just think it is out of date and if you are wrapping it, you might be better off writing your own.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts--great points. As for your point #5, really, clients have to include the log4net dll even though the wrapper would have a reference to it? Am I missing something basic about how .NET assemblies work? Curious to find out what you come up with for your logging needs, do post an update when it's ready.